# How to clear all history (included all sessions , cache etc) in IE with selenium webdriver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, browser-session, ie

I have one scenario to automate :

> Verify login with valid input

**Problem Statement**  : *Whenever I run script in IE for second time, Found all previous session are stored as it is . (Not found this same situation in Chrome and in Firefox)*

---

**My configuration :**

- Windows 10
- Selenium 3.4.0
- IE 11

**Code :**

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, url);
cap.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", false);
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS, true);
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_PERSISTENT_HOVERING, false);
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ELEMENT_SCROLL_BEHAVIOR, 1);
cap.setCapability("cssSelectorsEnabled", true);
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.NATIVE_EVENTS, false);

WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
```

I want to **clear all the history** which is given in this picture with **`Selenium Webdriver + IE`** just before starting script.

[image]

*Note : If is there any other way to avoid it please let me know.*

Comment: Why you need it? Anything specific?

Comment: @NarendraC Actually whenever I open new IE browser for same script. It take all history from previous browser even after quite. So I am require to kill sessions if possible.

Comment: Manually check - If you have opted "start from where you left". Disable that, It will work as per your requirment

Comment: No all settings are perfect. Even if it stores all previous data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting EnsureCleanSession to true?

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);

OR

cap.setCapability("ie.ensureCleanSession", true);
```

> When set to true, this capability clears the cache, cookies, history, and saved form data. When using this capability, be aware that this clears the cache for all running instances of Internet Explorer, including those started manually. [quoted from SeleniumHQ](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities)

Comment: can you please provide code ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include code examples and the description of the capability from SeleniumHQ

Comment: It is running perfectly.